# css div margin-right not working

Tags: html, css, margin

I made a simple navigation bar at the top of the page, and inside the nav bar there is an image. I want to align the image to the right of the nav bar, but for some reason it won't align to the right. I've tried the following on the image:

```
margin-right: 0;
right: 0;
margin-right: 0%;
```

etc

Here's my code:

```
<div id="navBar">
    <img src="" id="navPNG">
</div>

#navPNG {
    left: 50;
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    display: block;
}

#navBar {
    background-color: #3B3B3B;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
}
```

Keep in mind I would like the navBar to remain at the top of the page no matter how far down the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

try float:right to the image

#navPNG
    {
    float:right;
    }

Answer (score 0):

It's so simple, just use `float: right` to move the image to the right.

And add `top: 0` to the `#navBar` element to fix it to the top.

```
#navBar {
    background-color: #3B3B3B;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
}

#navPNG {
   float: right;
}
```

Another way by adding `text-align: right` to the container:

```
#navBar {
    background-color: #3B3B3B;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 75px;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}

#navPNG {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
 #navBar {
        background-color: #3B3B3B;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 75px;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #navPNG {
        right: 12px;
        width: 75px;
        height: 75px;
margin-right: 14px;
        position: absolute;
    }
```